# Batch rename multiple files using wildcards in powershell command

Tags: powershell

How can I batch rename multiple files found in the same folder (despite their original filenames) using a formula consisting of a fixed part and a changing part that is composed of 4 numerical digits starting from 0001 in powershell commandlet

i.e. output filenames:

```
Greenfarm_0001
Greenfarm_0002
Greenfarm_0003
Greenfarm_0004
Greenfarm_0006
```

Thank you

Comment: How do the original file names look like? Or you don't care at all about the input?

Comment: The original file name can be anything, I don't care about the input.

Answer (score 4):

If you want a one liner like,

```
Dir | %{Rename-Item $_ -NewName ("Prefix_{0}.jpg" -f $nr++)}
```

- you need to initialize the counter first
- Rename-Item accepts piped input, so no foreach neccessary
- to update the counter in the script block you need to use `([ref]$nr).Value++`

---

```
$nr=1;Get-ChildItem -Filter *.jpg|Rename-Item -Newname {"Greenfarm_{0:d4}.jpg" -f ([ref] $nr).Value++} -WhatIf
```

If the output looks OK, remove the `-WhatIf`

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
$prefix = "prefix_"
$counter = 1
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\temp" -File | foreach {

    Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName "$prefix$counter$($_.Extension)"
    $counter++
}
```

It reads all files within the given path and renames them using a specified prefix and an increasing number.

Use `Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\temp" -File -Recursive` to do the same for subfolders as well.

Comment: Thank you TobyU,
I need something that can be used in powershell like this one:
Dir | %{Rename-Item $_ -NewName ("Prefix_{0}.jpg" -f $nr++)} while {0} is supposed to be a 4-digits number starting from 0001.

Comment: @Fredes `{0}` -> `{0:d4}`

Comment: @Fredes If you need it as a one-liner, just write it as a one-liner: 
$prefix = "prefix_"; $counter = 1; Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\temp" -File | foreach { Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName "$prefix$counter$($_.Extension)"; $counter++; }

Comment: Thank you TobyU for one-liner idea, and thanks @AnsgarWiechers, the modification you suggested worked perfect except that it will start numbering at 0000 instead of 0001. ****** Dir | %{Rename-Item $_ -NewName ("Prefix_{0:d4}.jpg" -f $nr++)} ********